# Объявление экземпляра внутреннего класса

Tags: java, классы, переменные, объявление

Объявляется внутренний класс, и нужно создать его экземпляр.
Делаю в два шага. Не могу найти, можно ли делать в один?

```
public class HighScoreWriter {
   private class NewPlace{
      boolean isNewHS = false;
      int newHighScoreIndex = -1;
   }
   private NewPlace newPlace;
}
```

Comment: new NewPlace() не работает? Если да, то что пишет?

Comment: Что значит `в два шага`? `в один`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы создать экземпляр внутреннего класса ([inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)) необходимо сначала создать экземпляр внешнего класса. Пример:

```
public class HighScoreWriter {
    private class NewPlace { ... }
    ...
    public static void main(String... args) {
        HighScoreWriter hsw = new HighScoreWriter();
        HighScoreWriter.NewPlace np = hsw.new NewPlace();
        ...
    }
}
```

А если использовать статический внутренний класс ([static nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)), то можно создать его экземпляр за один вызов конструктора. Но изнутри статического внутреннего класса нельзя обращаться к экземпляру внешнего класса. Например:

```
public class HighScoreWriter {
    public static class NewPlace { ... }
}
public class AnotherClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        HighScoreWriter.NewPlace np = new HighScoreWriter.NewPlace();
        ...
    }
}
```